# How to replace a word to another word in a list python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

If I have this list:

```
['hello', 'world', 'goodbye', 'world', 'food']
```

Is it possible to replace every `world` to any other word without using any auto command, I am thinking about something like this:

```
if 'world' in list:
    'world' in list == 'peace'
```

Comment: What is an auto command ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist something like list.replace()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with an if-else.

```
list_A = ['hello', 'world', 'goodbye', 'world']
list_B = [word if word != 'world' else 'friend' for word in list_A]
```

You now have a new list, `list_B`, where all instances of the word "world" have been replaced with "friend".

Answer (score 1):

If you have unique values in your list:

```
my_list[my_list.index('old_word')]='new_word'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an out of the box solution e.g. something like my_list.replace() that you are looking for. Thus, the simple solution is just to iterate through the entire list (using enumerate to preserve the iterative variable).

Try this:

```
for index, elem in enumerate(my_list):
    if elem == "world":
        my_list[index] = "peace"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an expanded view of what is happening in Zach's answer

```
word_list = ['hello', 'world', 'goodbye', 'world', 'food']
for ndx, word in enumerate(word_list):
    if word == 'world':
        word_list[ndx] = 'peace'
print word_list
# result: ['hello', 'peace', 'goodbye', 'peace', 'food']
```

Comment: I believe the `if` statement should be `if word == 'world'` rather than `if 'world' in word_list`

Comment: You know you should enumerate `word_list`.

Comment: fixed that issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your question, but it should work:

```
lst = ['hello', 'world', 'goodbye', 'world', 'food']

lst = [i.replace('world', 'peace') for i in lst]

print(lst2)
```

"**If**" statement isn't needed. Cause if '**world**' not exist, it will just ignore it

Comment: This will fail with a word like "underworld".

Answer (score 0):

Although there isn't any `list.replace()` method in the python standard library.

But this utility function may help you:

```
def replace(l, target_word, replaced_word):
    for index, element in enumerate(l):
        if element == target_word:
            l[index] = replaced_word

    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def customReplaceFunction(wordList, replacingWord):
    for i in range(len(wordList)):
        if wordList[i] == 'world':
            wordList[i] = replacingWord
    print wordList
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over list and replace "world" with "peace"

```
wordlist = ['hello', 'world', 'goodbye', 'world', 'food']


for i in range(0,len(wordlist)):
   if wordlist[i]=="world":
      wordlist[i]="peace"
print(wordlist) 

wordlist = ['hello', 'peace', 'goodbye', 'peace', 'food']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map over each world and replace with a suitable word.

Using a lambda function,

```
words = map(lambda word: word.replace('world', 'peace') , l)
```